# Preg Match 2 tags

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm having some problems with building a scraper.
In the code i need to find
`<dt class="sc-ellipsis">Categorie</dt><dd>Tweedehands</dd>`

I need to find Tweedehands but only after the dt Categorie

My code that i have is

```
    $link = 'https://www.autoscout24.be'.$autolink;
    $html = file_get_contents($link);
    preg_match("'<dt class=\"sc-ellipsis\">Categorie</dt><dd>(.*?)</dd>'si", $html, $match);
```

I've been trying with SimpleDomHtml also but i can't figure it out on how to work.

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: So, what is the problem with the regex approach?

Comment: I don't know it just doesn't show anything when i use 

preg_match("'<dd>(.*?)</dd>'si", $html, $match);

I get some values but on the 
preg_match("'<dt class=\"sc-ellipsis\">Categorie</dt><dd>(.*?)</dd>'si", $html, $match);

I don't get any results

Comment: Can you provide the full url you are scrapping?